# Visual C# form that sends email attachment with string data in PDF or HTML

Tags: c#, email, pdf, attachment

I have created a functioning ASPX form in Visual C#. Now I need to make this output look a better. It needs to come in as an attachment because it is going into a web database that cannot render HTML. I've found that I run into conflicts between System.Web.Mail (deprecated) and System.Net.Mail. Whether I use one or the other does not matter.

I have found that there are 2 lines of code (below with " Attachment ") that make sending a files possible. How do I get my string data into the attachment when the email is sent?

Ive tried using MVC and/or iTextsharp, and had no luck.

Can someone look at my code and point me in the right direction or give me a clear concise working script that I can use to pull this off?

```
    <script language="C#" runat=server >private void btnSendmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string ITSPPSoftwareProcurementProcessRequest = String.Empty;
    System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(); 
    const string SERVER = "10.111.8.177"; 
    const string FileContents = null; 
    MailMessage oMail = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
    oMail.Attachments.Add(MailAttachment.CreateAttachmentFromString("ITSPPSoftwareProcurementProcessRequest", "pdf")); 
    oMail.Attachments.Last().ContentDisposition.FileName = "filename.pdf"; oMail.From = "system@mail.com"; 
    oMail.To = "myemail@mail.com"; 
    oMail.Subject = "request.system.com - Procurement Process Request Form"; 
    oMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text; 

    // enumeration oMail.Priority = MailPriority.High; 
    // enumeration oMail.Body = "Sent at: " + DateTime.Now + "\r\n\r\n" + ITSPPSoftwareProcurementProcessRequest; 
    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = SERVER; 
    SmtpMail.Send(oMail); oMail = null; 

    // free up resources 
    Response.Redirect ("thankyou.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Sorry.. The " Code " in place for posts is alittle goofy on the GUI side..

Comment: anyone have any ideas?